# I want to get the values of a row of a spreadsheet based on the selected cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, return-value, google-apps-script-editor, getvalue

I need to get all values of a row of a spreadsheet based on the cell that I have selected.
Example: I have selected the Cell F1. Now I want the all value in that row (for example F1, F2, F3, F4, F5).

What I tried:

```
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSelection()

  var val1 = selection.getValue()
  var val2 = values.getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getValue()
  var val3 = values.getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).getValue()
  ...
```

Then I thought I could selection the whole row in which I am interested so that I have a list of all values that I could get with xy[0], xy[1], xy[2]... but that was not succesful.

```
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data').getSelection().getActiveRange();
  
  var val1 = values[0]
  var val2 = values[1]
  ...
```

```
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
  var val1 = values[0]
  var val2 = values[1]
  ...
```

My last idea was to get just the position of the selected cell, e.g. F1. Thus I could get all values directly:

```
  var value1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 0).getValue();
  var value1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 1).getValue();
  var value1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(5, 2).getValue();
  ...
```

Unfortunately nothing worked so far. Has someone a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you actually want to retrieve the values in the selected `row`, and not `column` (so, if `F1` is selected, you want to retrieve `A1`, `B1`, `C1`, etc., not `F1`, `F2`, `F3`, etc., you can just do this:

- Get the row index of the selected cell, via [getCurrentCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcurrentcell) and [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRow()).
- Get the values corresponding to that row with [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) (specifying that the first row is the current row index, which was retrieved in previous step, and that the last column refers to the last column with content ([getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)), and [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) which returns a 2D array corresponding to the specified range. The first element of this 2D array is a simple array with all the values in the row.

#### Code sample:

```js
function getRowValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowIndex = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();
  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  return rowValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get an array of selected rows

```
function selectRowsBasedOnCriteria() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Your Sheet Name');//enter sheet name
  const sr=2;
  const sc=1;
  const rg=sh.getRange(sr,sc,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,sh.getLastColumn()-sc+1);
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let oA=[];
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[4]>10) {//selection criteria you chose whatever you want
      oA.push(r);//save selected row
    }
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(oA.join('<br />')).setWidth(800), "Rows");//just a way of displaying the selected rows
  //const osh=ss.getSheetByName('output');//to display in another sheet
  //osh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues();//display in another sheet
  return oA;//this is an array of selected rows
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helpS already as I get the values of a row in an array now! But I have a few questions though:

I implemented your code to my scripteditor and I get a display of the selected values (Very nice!). I thought, as oA is now an array with the values, I could get the values by like:

```
 var value1 = oA[1]
 var value2 = oA[2]
 ...
```
But this does not work. How can I get the single values?

I have another problem. Is seems that it does not work when there is a column with no entry. In that case I do not get the display of the selected values.. Is there a trick?

Comment: I guess Iamblichus answer is sufficient for me, but thanks anyway!